# cannot request additional permission publish_actions alone

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm running into a strange bug...
I'm asking for publish_actions permissions (I want to publish on the user's timeline the dive he just logged on diveboard.com  ), and since I may want this to work in bulk (like publish all my dives) i want it done in the back and not through the front. I still want to request the permission on the front interactively.

When I ask only for "publish_actions", the popup opens and closes immediately and obviously the permission was not granted (checked in privacy)

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.perms != undefined && response.perms.match(/publish\_actions/)!=null) {
      G_user_fbtoken = getFBCookie().accessToken;
      fbtimelinepublish_dive();
      } else {
        // user cancelled login
        diveboard.notify("Unsufficient privileges","Could not get the adequate permissions to publish this action on your timeline");
        toggle_fb_spinner();
        return;
      }
    }, {scope:'publish_actions'});
}else{
  fbtimelinepublish_dive();
}
```

Any clue !?

update :  I tried with : scope:'create_event,publish_actions,publish_stream,rsvp_event'

and got

[image: auth window]

[image: resulting permisions]

Comment: So I'm self-answering a solution :

While in Open Graph Beta, the 'publish_actions' permission can only be requested from developers and test users of your app. The 'publish_actions' permission will be ignored if requested from any other user.

and I moved to the new auth window....

hopefully this will save some frustrations to others....

Answer (score 1):

So I'm self-answering a solution : While in Open Graph Beta, the 'publish_actions' permission can only be requested from developers and test users of your app. The 'publish_actions' permission will be ignored if requested from any other user. and I moved to the new auth window.... hopefully this will save some frustrations to others....